# Allegro displaying weird corrupt visuals

Tags: c, osx-elcapitan, allegro, allegro5

I have been trying to use Allegro but finding that sometimes when I call `al_flip_display` instead of the expected result, I get a display of corrupt messy nonsense, sometimes white noise, sometimes sections of other portions of my screen. To me that seems like the buffer is sharing memory with something else but I have no real idea what could be causing it.

I've tried to write a minimal program that demonstrates this problem. What is meant to happen is that every time a key is pressed another section of a diagonal line is drawn on the display. What actually happens is when I press a key I get a corrupt visual mess, and then when I press a key again I get what I am expecting, pressing it again goes back to the mess, pressing it again gives what I want. I.e. it seems to only affect one of the buffers.

There's a couple of screenshots at the bottom of what kind of thing happens when a key is pressed.

Any ideas?

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>

int main(void)
{
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    if (!al_init()) return 1;
    if (!al_init_primitives_addon()) return 1;

    display = al_create_display(640, 480);

    if (!display) return 1;

    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        al_draw_line(0+i*20, 0+i*20, 50+i*20, 50+i*20, al_map_rgb(255,255,255), 1);
        al_flip_display(); // this is where the error happens
        getchar(); // wait for next keypress
    }

    al_destroy_display(display);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and executed with the following on OS X El Capitan with Allegro 5.0:

```
clang `pkg-config allegro-5.0 allegro_main-5.0 allegro_primitives-5.0 --cflags --libs` test1.c -o test1.o && ./test1.o
```

Note that this doesn't seem to happen for me when I run it with MinGW on Windows. Only on my OS X laptop does it happen. Haven't tried it on anything else. Could it be a bug with Allegro in OS X?

[image: An example of what happens]
[image: Another example]

Comment: can't repro on linux. It almost looks like a window manager issue (those 'corrupt' bits look like graphics from other windows on your desktop). Try `al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0))` at the start of the loop.

Comment: You could try using a VM running windows on that laptop and run the progarm there to ser if tjis causes the glith, but it looks like some hardware/windows mánager issue or a graphic card that is dying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a note to anyone with this problem. The issue was a bug in Allegro in OS X El Capitan, and the solution was to use the development version of Allegro where the bug is fixed.

As this was a few months ago, those changes may be in the production version now.

Comment: Doesn't change that this program is still bugged. The backbuffer is undefined before you draw to it so my answer below still stands. Allegro now clears the backbuffer for you but this is still undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is a blast from the past! Thank you for your message. In this case clearing the back buffer as you suggested did not solve the problem. The original code which this was taken from did call `al_clear_to_color` - I neglected to include that in the simplified case I posted in the listing. My apologies for not responding to that effect at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the backbuffer each time you flip. After `al_flip_display()`, the contents of the backbuffer are undefined, which means the OS/gfx drivers can put/leave anything there. Use `al_clear_to_color` at the top of your loop.